# HTML Carousel not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, carousel

I am trying to get my carousel to function, but when clicking on the arrows, the slides don't change.

This is my code, 
http://codepen.io/rkrc/pen/ogPaqM

HTML:

```
<div class="slider"> 
 <!-- picture 01 -->
  <div class="slide active-slide">
   <div class="container">
    <img src="image"> 
   </div>
  </div>
 <!-- picture 02 -->
  <div class="slide">
   <div class="container">
    <img src="image"> 
   </div>
  </div>
 <!-- picture 03 -->
  <div class="slide">
   <div class="container">
    <img src="image">
   </div>
  </div>
 <!-- picture 04 -->
  <div class="slide">
   <div class="container">
    <img src="image">
   </div>
  </div>
 <!-- picture 05 -->
  <div class="slide">
   <div class="container">
    <img src="image">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Slider nav -->
  <div class="slider-nav"> 
   <a href="" class="arrow-prev"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png"></a>
     <ul class="slider-dots">
      <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
       </ul>
    <a href="" class="arrow-next"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png"></a> 
   </div>
   <!--End of slide show-->
```

CSS:

```
/* Carousel */

.slider {
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #f7f7f7;
 border-top: 10px solid #f7f7f7;
}

.slide {
 text-align: center;
 background: #f7f7f7;
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.active-slide {
 display: block;
}

.slider-nav {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.arrow-prev {
 margin-right: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-top: 9px;
}

.arrow-next {
 margin-left: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-top: 9px;
}

.slider-dots {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slider-dots li {
 color: #bbbcbc;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
 color: #363636;
}
```

JS:

```
 var main = function(){
//Carousel
$('.arrow-next').click(function(){

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide= currentSlide.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0){
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeout(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.faseIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextDot.length === 0){
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
 });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

This is what I am trying to achieve, following the codecademy example.
http://codepen.io/rkrc/pen/Wbappy

Comment: Few typos - fasein...fadeout - should be fadeOut... fix it, and let us know if there are more problems... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pwypye

Comment: @nevermind fixed the typos, nice catch, my bad :{ 
Saw what you did in codepen, adding
 `$('.arrow-next').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();`
 Made the carousel move, but it had a weird effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typos in the code as *nevermind* mentioned. fasein() should be `fadeIn()` and fadeout() needs to be capitalized to `fadeOut()`. However even with these fixes you may still run into some problems as the slider will show the next slide in the series before the `fadeOut()` animation is complete. Best to put the `fadeIn()` animation and target next slide in the callBack function of the active slide animation. Here's an example of something you could do:

```
     currentSlide.fadeOut(600, function(){

         $(this).removeClass('active-slide');

         nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide'); 

     });
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Fixing the typos and adding what @nevermind did 
`$('.arrow-next').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();`
Then following what you, @hugorut did, made the carousel move fluidly.

Answer (score 0):

My changes to the JS file:

```
var main = function(){
//Carousel

//arrow-next

$('.arrow-next').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); //Added this

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide= currentSlide.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0){
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
    }

  currentSlide.fadeOut(600, function() { //Fixed spelling errors
     $(this).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide'); //Fixed spelling errors
  });

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextDot.length === 0){
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
});

//Followed the same pattern for arrow-prev

//arrow-prev

$('.arrow-prev').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide= currentSlide.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length === 0){
        prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
    }

  currentSlide.fadeOut(600, function() {
     $(this).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
  });

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if(prevDot.length === 0){
        prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
 });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Final product http://codepen.io/rkrc/pen/ogPaqM